# API implementation Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I am tasked with taking these two APIs:

https://api.secondharvestvfd.com/v1/banks/1/drives/392/teams/397

https://api.secondharvestvfd.com/v1/banks/1/drives/392/teams/399

Calculating the result of team_raised * bank_meals_to_dollar from both, adding them together and outputting the result in a ticker on a wordpress site.

I've got no idea how to start.

Would it be a matter of writing some PHP to create API Shortcodes in order to perform the multiplication and addition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Curl with php in wordpress
Code :

```
<?php 

function getApi($url){
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);


$response_ = json_decode($response, true);
return $response_;

}

$respon_1 = getApi("https://api.secondharvestvfd.com/v1/banks/1/drives/392/teams/397");
$team_raised_1 = floatval($respon_1['team_raised']);
$bank_meals_to_dollar_1 = floatval($respon_1['bank_meals_to_dollar']);
$result_1 = $team_raised_1 * $bank_meals_to_dollar_1;


$respon_2 = getApi("https://api.secondharvestvfd.com/v1/banks/1/drives/392/teams/399");
$team_raised_2 = floatval($respon_2['team_raised']);
$bank_meals_to_dollar_2 = floatval($respon_2['bank_meals_to_dollar']);
$result_2 = $team_raised_2 * $bank_meals_to_dollar_2;
$value_tot = $result_2 + $result_1;
echo $value_tot;
```

Comment: There are WordPress functions for remote get https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/93991/wp-remote-get-vs-file-get-contents-vs-curl

Comment: @Alaa can you message me - eyeopner@gmail.com

Comment: this works and displays properly but it breaks the page. I'm inserting it using shortcode plugins. Do you think it would be worth implementing it by creating my own shortcode or placing it directly in the php of the page?

Comment: if know the place of the file where you wanna display it ,it will be more easy by implementing it manually .